# Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly error with code which previously worked

Tags: python, string, pyqt, integer, pyqt4

```
self.itemCode.setText(str(getNumber()))
```

This calls getNumber() to get the item ID for the next item to be added to be displayed to the user:

```
def getNumber():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence')
    itemNumber = c.fetchone()[0]
    code = str(itemNumber + 1)
    return code
```

Earlier, I got it to work. Using the code above... I don't know what happened but now it returns.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/addItem.py", line 239, in <module>
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/addItem.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/addItem.py", line 176, in setupUi
    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/addItem.py", line 185, in retranslateUi
    self.itemCode.setText(str(getNumber()))
  File "C:/Users/Lloyd/Desktop/Python Projects/stock/addItem.py", line 26, in getNumber
    return itemNumber + 1

  TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: `itemNumber` is string.

Comment: can you print what is `itemNumber `

Comment: `str(int(itemNumber) + 1)`.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, it is an int! @KalyanReddy

Comment: Can you check it again, i think type error happened here because you are trying to add a string with integer

Comment: I've added my answer now. It seems Python doesn't recognize it anymore as an int. Previously, Python did. @KalyanReddy

Comment: Which is most likely:  that python suddenly, without warning, switches the type of a variable at a whim, or that you either misunderstood what it was doing or changed something else as well?

Comment: Nope. Nothing has been changed. @cdarke

Comment: Reproduce the error and report it as a serious python bug then.  Good luck!

Comment: @cdarke I'm a beginner. Why do you think I'm asking simple bugs in my code here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello lloydyu24,**

Try this code,

```
def getNumber():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence')
    itemNumber = c.fetchone()[0]
    code = int(itemNumber) + 1
    return str(code)

self.itemCode.setText(getNumber())
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. So, basically, you need to convert itemNumber(which is the sequence number in my sqlite database table) to int first before adding with 1.

```
def getNumber():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence')
    itemNumber = c.fetchone()[0]
    return int(itemNumber) + 1 #CHANGED THIS from "return str(itemNumber + 1)"
```

Previously, it worked. I don't know what happened but Python doesn't recognize itemNumber as an int anymore.

Answer (score 0):

itemNumber is a string, so in your code:

```
code = str(itemNumber + 1)
```

You are trying to add a number (1) to a string (itemNumber).
First, you should cast the string into an int, and afterwards add the number (1) to it:

`code = str (int (itemNumber) + 1)`

Good luck!